# Unable to draw shape after shapefile merge

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, arccatalog

I have merged a bunch of shapefiles in ArcCatalog and get the "the selected file failed to draw...." error. Every thing has merged alright in the db.

I'm new to GIS and could use some help.

Each of the shapefiles that were imported to ArcCatalog are an aggregate of the following file extensions:
•.dbf
•.prj
•.shp
•.shp (xml)
•.shx

Comment: please explain the software version, also the tool used to merge. I do hope you didn't manually merge each file type. That will not work. please explain the process you used.

Comment: I am in ArcCatalog 10.2.2.  The following is the process I used: ArcToolbox --> Data Management Tools --> General --> Merge -->  Selected files to `Merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some definite known limitations regarding using shapefiles, but if you are looking to consistently use large datasets with too many features for a shapefile, I'd see if merging the shapefiles into a feature class in a File Geodatabase would work with your workflow as geodatabases are much more efficient at handling large datasets.  Additionally, as mentioned by @Michael_Miles-Stimson (see comment to other answer) there other additional benefits to using a geodatabase rather than a shapefile. The main consideration before committing to a switch away from the shapefile is to make sure all intended users of the data will be using software that can utilize the new data format.  Shapefile is a very widely recognized standard accepted by most GIS software, though the File Geodatabase is usable by a growing number of GIS softwares as well and is definitely usable by ArcGIS & QGIS systems.

The following link documents some of the known limitations of Shapefile size that I think may be the cause of your issue: http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37447

Comment: Thanks again for your input...very new to Arc (like a week new)...the majority of my experience falls within SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ArcCatalogue doesn't like to handle alot of records at once.  I solved the problem by merging 5 shape files at a time.  I was warned about the inefficiencies of Arc :/

Comment: There are some definite known limitations regarding using shapefiles, but if you are looking to consistently use large datasets with too many features for a shapefile, I'd see if merging the shapefiles into a feature class in a File Geodatabase would work with your workflow as geodatabases are much more efficient at handling large datasets.

Comment: It's not Arc that's inefficient in this case, it's the shapefile. Each of the files have a limit of 2GB but only the .dbf and .shp are likely to hit that limit. I have done a merge operation in SDE from fGDB with more than 10 million records (roads) and it worked just fine (~3 hours). Shapefiles are a handy format for going between QGIS/ArcGis/MapINFO/... to work with feature classes as @John said consider using File Geodatabase (fGDB, readable in QGIS) - better indexing, larger table sizes, faster fetch rates, domains, subtypes, topology.. there are *many* benefits.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson do you want to add your answer as this worked way better than mine.  I created the File Geodatabase and was a way better solution.  I will accept your answer an leave mine unanswered.

Comment: @John See above comment.  As you are both right, whoever posts it as an answer first will be accepted. Yours and Michael's answered proved way more efficient and effective