# Working w/ Shapefiles Containing 50,000 to 300,000 Features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, select, large-datasets

I work daily with shapefiles that are quite large in number of features using ArcGIS. Sometimes I am able to perform operations (joins, selections, exports, etc) on these shapefiles (though they do take quite a bit of time to run- usually ~5 to 10 minutes) and sometimes I am not. I am working in ArcMap 10.2.2 and have tried many things from clearing my cache to closing all other programs while these operations occur to attempting to break down the size of these files. I should also note that my system far exceeds Arc's minimum requirements.

Any tips/advice?

Comment: See answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148831/unable-to-draw-shape-after-shapefile-merge/149007#149007  for some related info

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Sometimes I am able to perform operations [...] and sometimes I am not"? What happens when you are not able to perform the operation?

Comment: Convert your shapefiles to geodatabase feature classes they generally perform better. You can also use the 'Add Attribute Index' tool to index your table this should help.

Comment: so converting the shapefiles to gdb feature classes made the joins infinitely quicker, but im still given trouble by selections and exporting. the feature class im currently working in has 326000 records. any ideas?

also, thanks to all who recommended the file conversion!!

Comment: @John

you are a lifesaver

Comment: Welcome. As far as other ideas, the only other thing that readily comes to mind about the situation wouldn't be specific to large datasets, but in general when working with joins, you have to be very careful with tools that require specific field names and/or list of fields (such as field mapping in append and FC to FC GP tool). With a join, you could have multiple fields with the same field name (one from each table), so you have to make sure you're listing and selecting the correct field(s) in the correct spot/order as required.  May or may not be your issue, but good to keep in mind anyway.

Comment: beware that shapefiles have definite size limits, 2GB per part (but only .shp & .dbf are likely to hit that) this could by why some operations don't work. Personal geodatabases also have a similar limit but file geodatabases can be up to many terrabytes. If your joins are failing have a look at what you're joining to, Excel and text are known to be flaky, best to import into a geodatabase table to avoid issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with ArcMap not recognizing the full data set when the number of records in a single table is very large.

I manually "force" ArcMap to recognize the size of the data set I want to join to by opening the table and clicking on the **Move to end of table** button.

See this graphic:

[image: View of Table]

As you can see I was working with nearly half a million records and once I forced ArcMap to scroll to the last record it behaved just fine.